# Eclipse showing different plugins for OS X and Ubuntu. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, plugins

Eclipse showing different plugins for OS X and Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, I cannot see the latest versions of the plugin.
Why?

Pics:

1. OS X http://postimg.org/image/yl734j8bj/
2. Ubuntu http://postimg.org/image/vg501i1ut/

Both, OS X and Ubuntu are running Juno Service Release 2.

Ubuntu is running the latest jdk from oracle.

Ubuntu is being virtualized via parallels.

):<